# How to use two create ActionResult from two different model in the same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched how to handle that but I found nothing so far. There is my issue, I have a post model, and a comment model. My CreateView has input to create a post, and it's also display in this create view. Let's see the code :

**EDIT2 : Add the CreateComment Action Result in my PostController ; & the ActionLink in my partial ListPost view**

*Now I could see my link to add a comment, it send my on my CreateComment view, but when I try to save it in my DB, i've got this error :*

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Posts_PostId\". The conflict occurred in
>   database \Myproject", table \"dbo.Posts\", column 'PostId'.\r\nThe
>   statement has been terminated."

PostController

```
        public ActionResult ListPost()
        {
            var post = db.Posts.ToList();
            return PartialView("ListPost", post);
        }


        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(); 
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection values)
        {
            var post = new Post();
            TryUpdateModel(post);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var context = new UsersContext();
                var username = User.Identity.Name;
                var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                var userid = user.UserId;                

                post.UserId = userid;
                post.Date = DateTime.Now;

                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post"); 
            }
            return View(post);
        }


    public ActionResult CreateComment()
    {
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content");
        return View("CreateComment");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(FormCollection values)
    {
        var comment = new Comment();
        TryUpdateModel(comment);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userid = user.UserId;

            comment.UserId = userid;
            comment.Date = DateTime.Now;

            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post");
        }
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content", comment.PostId);
        return View(comment);
    }
```

Create view :

```
@model Myproject.Models.Post

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post", FormMethod.Post))
{  
        <legend>Add Post</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
            <input type="file" name="Photo" id="Photo"/>
        </div>   

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </p> 
}

@{Html.RenderAction("ListPost", "Post");}
```

ListPost view

```
    @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Post>

    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.UserName)</span>    
            </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
       <td> @Html.ActionLink("Add Comment", "CreateComment", new {id=item.PostId})</td>      
    </tr>
 }
```

Now, I would like add comment to a post. My comment model (and table) has a postId property. How can I include my createCommentView in my ListPost view, I think I must include it in this view rather than in my CreatePostView but I'm not sure either. In both cases, I don't know how to do it, cause I'm using a Comment Model and a Post Model in the same view...

Any ideas, link where you could send me to, or anything ? 
Thank you, and sorry for my bad English

Comment: They can be in the same view.. but your forms need to post to the correct controllers.. and the forms should not be nested (they should be separate. E.g, `<form></form><form></form>` and not `<form><form></form></form>`).

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Even if I create another form in my ListPost view, this one is typed with IEnumerable<Post> so I can't reach my comment model and write something like `@Html.EditorFor(m => item.Comment.Content)` right ?

Comment: Create a ViewModel that encompasses both a post and a comment and just pass the comment id in through a hidden field: `@Html.Hidden("postID", Model.Post.ID)`. Then when the comment form posts to the action you'll have the postID to which it is associated.

Comment: I've tried that, and write a view model with this two properties `public List<Post> Posts` and `public Comment CreateComment` that I call in my ListPost view, but in the return of my ListPost actionresult, he tells me on the argument "post" that List<Post> is not assignable to CommentViewModel.. And thank you for the Hidden field, I wondered how to bind my comment with the post.

Comment: Removed tag MVVM, as this is not a WPF application - just to reduce confusion...

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Comment", "CreateComments", new { id=item.PostId })
```

make sure to pass PostId as a property to your model.

Comment: To add this ActionLink, I should have the CreateComments method in my PostController ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping me. So I've done that, but now i've got the an error, a conflict with my postId when I try to save it in my db. I've edited my post.

Comment: do u get any value for PostId in values collection, in CreateComment function, I dont think so, coz you are not passing this value to the controller, You need to pass this value from the view.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by passing the PostId value to the controller from the view ? What should I do ? I'm thinking about that : `return View("CreateComment", comment)` in my get ActionResult CreateComment, but not sure at all...

Comment: I add an HiddenFor field for my PostId in my CreateComment view, I don't have any error anymore, but nothing happens. Sorry, it's all new for me

Comment: when u add @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId) in comments view, check what value you get for PostId in values collection, in CreateComment function?

Comment: I've deleted the HiddenField and adding the three lines (see my answer), and it work. Does it seems right to you ? Thanks for your help

Comment: I have seen ur added lines, the idea was to pass post id to comments table when saving records to comments table(as post is is foreign key in comments table), which u did by ading these lines, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With the awnser of Niraj and with adding the three lines specified under, it works fine

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(FormCollection values, int id)
    {
        var comment = new Comment();
        TryUpdateModel(comment);

        /** ADD THIS LINE **/
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userid = user.UserId;

            comment.UserId = userid;
            comment.Date = DateTime.Now;

            /***  ADD THIS TWO LINES ***/
            comment.Post = post;
            comment.PostId = post.PostId;

            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Post");
        }            
        ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Content", comment.PostId);
        return View(comment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

createCommentView should be partial view , which will be used below html of ListPost view, to this partial view pass post id.In partial view take one textbox for comment inside Html.BeginForm("Comment", "CreateComment", FormMethod.Post) and pass comment to new action CreateComment

partial view shd be like

```
@model Comment //comment class has post id and comment text

@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "CreateComment", FormMethod.Post))
{  
        <legend>Add Post</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostId)
        </div>   

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </p> 
}
```

Now in your list post view use this

```
@Html.Partial("CommentView", new Comment(){PostId=item.PostId})
```